# c# how to validate windows credentials in a different domain

Tags: c#, windows-authentication

Is there a way to validate windows credentials in a certain domain? I only have the users windows credentials I got with;

```
CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

When I had a password and such I used the below code;

```
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "SOME DOMAIN"))
{
   // validate the credentials
   bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by validate? By the pure fact that windows has logged them in, are they not already validated?

Comment: I have some users who have windows accounts for domain1 but use applications with another user for domain 2. I get the user's credentials as stated and need to validate it in domain2 or 3 etc.

Comment: Do you want just to check if a User exists in a certain domain? Because you only can validate a user if you have both UserName and Password

Comment: @lokusking I need to check if his windows credentials are actually valid in another domain. I can get the username but I don't have the password. From what I understand it is not possible.

Comment: Maybe just ask him for his password with a Dialog + PasswordBox?